# Marionette AppRouter not working with Browserify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, npm, marionette, browserify

app.js

```
module.exports = function () {
if (!window.__medicineManager) {
    var Backbone =  require('backbone'); 
    var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

    var MedicineManager = new Marionette.Application();

    MedicineManager.addRegions({
        mainRegion: "#main-region"
    });

    MedicineManager.navigate = function (route, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        Backbone.history.navigate(route, options);
    };

    MedicineManager.getCurrentRoute = function () {
        return Backbone.history.fragment;
    };

    MedicineManager.on("start", function () {
        if (Backbone.history) {
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    });

    MedicineManager.start();
    window.__medicineManager = MedicineManager;
}
return window.__medicineManager;
}();
```

medicine_app.js

```
var MedicineManager = require('app');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
MedicineManager.module("MedicineApp", function (MedicineApp) {
    MedicineApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes: {
            "": "showSearchOption",
            "show/*id": "showMedicine"
        }
    });

    var API = {
        showSearchOption: function () {
            console.log('show search option');
        },
        showMedicine: function (id) {
            console.log('show ' + id);
        }
    };

    MedicineManager.addInitializer(function () {
        console.log('MedicineApp.Router initialised');
        new MedicineApp.Router({
            controller: API
        });
    });
});
```

I know Marionette module is deprecated, so please ignore that as I am still testing Browserify.

The problem is that `"": "showSearchOption"` route is not being fired.

I issue is referred at [Marionette.AppRouter as Backbone.Router](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/2778)
and I can't understand how to solve it? 

**Edit:**
What I think is that the Backbone instance that Marionette is using internally is different from what I get when I `require('backbone')`.
Any suggestions to this problem?

Comment: are you sure Backbone.history.start() is called?

Comment: What do you mean by `Marionette module is deprecated`?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: the problem is that Marionette is requiring its own instance of Backbone.

I banged my head against this problem for a while before I hit on one solution. I solved this issue by upgrading to NPM v3, which has a flat dependency structure, and then setting `window.Backbone = require( 'backbone' );`.

If you don't want to do it this way, you can also, I think, use `peerDependencies`, which I learned a lot about [here](https://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/dealing-with-the-deprecation-of-peerdependencies-in-npm-3/). Note that I haven't tested this way of doing it; I'm happy to use NPM v3.